# I cant add more than a quantity of one of any product to my cart

Tags: inventory

I cant add more than a quantity of one of any product to my cart. This is for a customer and they are saying that it happened all of a sudden.  I checked sys>config>inventory.  Min qty is set to 10000.  Where else can I check?

Comment: Matt McLennan,Can you check at product level means admin>product grid

Comment: For each product?  I dont understand the path you've listed.

Comment: goto admin>Catalog>Manage Product> open a product>goto it Inventory tab> see  Min qty field

Comment: Min qty is 0, Max is 10000.No to Manage stock. This issue is site wide though.

Answer (score 1):

Please check settings in

```
System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
```

and

```
System->Configuration->Shipping Settings->Options->Maximum Qty Allowed for Shipping to Multiple Addresses
```

The topic was discussed here:

[Magento cart can only take one item (1 quantity per product)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38523/magento-cart-can-only-take-one-item-1-quantity-per-product)

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused by having the stock quantity set a level 1 for example and the system being set in system>configuration>catalog>inventory>backorders set to "No Backorders".

The same result is experienced.